Child accuses friend of stealing
My child had some cash in their jacket pocket at school and it was gone when he got home. He thinks maybe one of his friends stole it and wants to confront him.
Realistically, anyone could have stolen it. If he accuses his friend it will hurt his friends feelings.
While this is something we will talk about, I'm not sure we should talk about it some more and then leave it to him to decide what to do. In this case i plan to tell him to discuss the disappeared money with his class or at least with a group of friends without accusing anyone in particular. Is this the right course of action?
On one hand it feels wrong to disregard his hunch and to tell him to keep his suspicions to himself, even when it will bother him a lot. On the other hand, he has no proof and an
accusation like this could ruin their friendship.
They are only 11.


On one hand it feels wrong to disregard his hunch and to tell him to keep his suspicions to himself, even when it will bother him a lot.

A hunch is just a guess, maybe a good one, but still just a guess.
Everyone needs to learn to live with uncertainty. This may be an opportunity to bring that lesson home. He is in a safe place, and the uncertainty will not hurt him anywhere close to what would happen to him if he should mistakenly accuse anyone of taking the money.
Something else he can learn from this is integrity, that is, prioritizing doing the right thing over personal gain. What he might gain is a sum of money, but is it "the right thing" to accuse someone, overtly or covertly, of stealing when one is uncertain? That's a good discussion to have as well. Do unto others, and all that. Would he want to be confronted about theft if he were innocent?
Unless the money was removed from a zippered pocket or a wallet, there's the possibility that he lost the money unknowingly. Over time, he will lose money, and he will find money. It happens. Losing money is disappointing, but losing a friend by mistake is much more so.
I can't remember ever dealing with this as a parent, but if I had, I'd have discussed these things with my child, and propose (just propose, not instruct) that my child ask the teacher if any money had been turned in, and if not, to check with the "lost & found" spot at his school (usually in the principal's office). If neither yields results, he could ask the teacher to make an announcement about the money he lost. If someone found it and was thinking of keeping it, or if it was stolen and the thief is having second thoughts, it's an opportunity for the party involved to clear their conscience and give it back.
Obviously you'll want the child to be able to safely discuss all the feelings involved here with each scenario, including that of confronting his friend. Ultimately, after the conversations are done, it will be up to the child to choose their course of action. If they choose to accuse and it bites him in the rear, that's a good lesson, too. One can empathize with every scenario here, but at least the child has been forewarned.
Whenever I lose money, I don't fret. I just hope that whoever found it needed it more than I did, and if so, I'm glad they have it, and hope it's put to good use. That's how I deal with it. But for a child, that's much easier said than done.

I marked this as the answer, especially for the advice of discussing 'integrity' explicitly (rather then implicitly) and for the extra options like checking lost & found and involving the teacher.

The other answer is a good one, but to try to be a little more succinct and general I'd put it like this:

If the same situation [x] happened to an adult, and an adult reacted that way, how would you advise them?

There isn't really anything inherently different about the situation because it's happening to an 11 year old, it's just that your child doesn't know how to work out the solution himself, because he's 11. That's where you as a parent come in and explain the reality of the situation so he understands it. You might explain a few different ways to look at what happened, and, in your opinion, what the best way to respond is.
That's essentially your role as a parent, to train your kid into becoming an effective adult by explaining how the world works, and how to deal with it. So more generally - any problem he faces, you just want to give him positive and correct perspective about it, as an adviser would. You can't really control what he actually does, but that's not a problem because if he makes a bad decision he'll learn from that too. It's all experience. That's the point of childhood, for kids to experiment and learn while the stakes are low.
As a corollary of the above, this also means that you're taking your kid seriously as a person, and expecting more out of them, not less just because of their age. By setting the expectation that they can listen to reason, internalize advice, and follow through on that advice you're also going to encourage their maturity and problem solving skills.
So to summarize a little - I wouldn't worry too much about giving the 'right' advice in a situation like this, as long as you're doing your best to give 'good' advice, just as you would to anyone.
